# Display a 'loading' image till loading original images in 'image gallery app' - metro style

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, html, windows-runtime, winjs

I am developing an image gallery application ..

Its loading images from the internet..

What i am doing is collecting image url into an array  and bind it into a list view ..

Its works fine..  But my problem is the images shows a cross mark ( 'X') till loading the images.

What i am expecting is

1. Display a loading image for each emage untill loads the original image
2. if 1 is not possible, how can i remove the cross mark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot remove the 'X' mark as that is a browser-specific feature.  You could, however, set your images to have a background image of your loading image.

simple example:

```
<img src="" style="background-image: url(loadingimage.gif)" />
```

This way, your loader shows up and is masked when the full image loads.

Comment: Thanks .I gave background image .But still the 'X' is there . Cant i remove that too?

Comment: That X shows up because of the browser you are using.  For example, IE (most versions) show an X, but Firefox shows nothing.  Chrome has a little image that is like an X mark inside of a document.  That is controlled by the browser and I do not believe javascript or CSS can edit that.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to set the src to a 1x1 pixel transparent gif, set the dimensions to the final image size, the background image to a loading image, and then use JavaScript to load the image, and `onload` swap it into the placeholder gif

#### example

HTML

```
<img src="images/spacer.gif" alt="Big Image" border="0" id="big_image" style="background-image:url('loading.gif');" width="3396" height="2347" />
```

JS

```
var I = new Image();
I.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('big_image').src = I.src;
};
I.src = 'http://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/0911/ngc2623_hst_big.jpg';
```