# How to put a default image on a gridLayout Item?

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

I am curious about how to put a default image to a GridLayout item by using the templates. Can anyone provide any suggestions?

Here is my template

```
<div class="gridLayoutItemTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template" data-win- options="{tap: 'none'}">
    <div class="photoTemplate">
        <img class="photoTemplateImage" src="#" alt="" data-win-bind="src: imageUrl WinJS.Binding.oneTime; alt: title" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a new 'loading' image in the slution and  in the template 
just apply new style to the image and specify background image property

Example is shown below

```
  <img class="photoTemplateImage" src="#" alt="" data-win-bind="src: imageUrl WinJS.Binding.oneTime; alt: title"  style="background-image: url(loadingimage.gif)" />
```

You can add the background image property to the class.. So you can avoid using in line styles..

Change the url depend on where you storing the image

refer  [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9287962/461561)